# Integration of Alexa Voice Service with ionic

Tags: ionic4, alexa-skills-kit, alexa-voice-service

I want to build a hybrid ionic application for android and ios device for my alexa skill. Where my ionic application will catch user's voice and send it to alexa skill and afterthat processing from lambda function, the result will be speak out from ionic application. Is it possible with Alexa Voice Service? How to do that?

Answer (score 1):

That's not how the voice assistant devices work.

You can write a skill that can be used on the device.

Embedding Alexa into your application is not an option.

The only way Ionic Framework would come into play is if you built an admin panel to configure options for the skill.

You also asked about [Alexa Voice Service](https://developer.amazon.com/alexa-voice-service) in the comments. This is for embedding Alexa into your device. It is a full copy of Alexa added into your device, not a way to deploy your own Alexa Skill to a device.

Comment: Ok. Thats mean it's not possible to embed alexa into my ionic application. But there is a feature **Alexa voice service**, which has a android and ios paltform, how this is working?

Answer (score 0):

Hi we can integrate aws lex in ionic app, below is the link for reference.

https://aws-amplify.github.io/docs/js/angular#ionic-4-components

Comment: Can you specify using aws lex can I use Amazon lwa login and Alexa voice service API in my ionic application?